# Removing duplicates from array without Collections, simple question

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

So, firstly please forgive me for this question, it might be silly, but whats up with this line of code :

```
if (array[i] == newArray[j])
```

lets say we have an array with elements {1,1,2,2,3,4,5}
and when you create a new array : `int[] newArray = new int[array.length]` you basically initialize it with zeros, now comes the line i told you, how can you check the fact that `1 == 0` or next `1 == 0` , every time you check the equality you will check with zero, or I am missing something? Please somebody explain.

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] array) {
        Arrays.sort(array);

        int[] newArray = new int[array.length];
        for (int i : newArray) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            boolean isDuplicate = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < newArray.length; j++) {
                if (array[i] == newArray[j]) {
                    isDuplicate = true;
                }
            }

            if (!isDuplicate) {
                newArray[counter] = array[i];
                counter++;
            }
        }
        int[] result = Arrays.copyOf(newArray,counter);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: `What's up with this line of code?`  I don't know, I think it's a bug.  Are you asking because the code works and you want to know why?  Or are you asking because the code doesn't work?

Comment: I just tried the code and it does work fine for me. Maybe you get the wrong results because you have 0 in your input array and 0 is always taken as duplicate, since the newArray is filled with that number.

Comment: The values in `newArray` aren't `0` forever. Look more closely at the code.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Sure they arent, but every number is at least compared once to 0 as duplicate, so 0 will always be detected as duplicate. I did not even look at the code but did also debug it, so yes I know that my input is valid.

Comment: @ManuelManhart My comment was directed at the OP. I agree the code doesn’t handle zero correctly.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Ah, okay, sorry then ;-)

Comment: array : 1,1,2,2,3,4,5 , newArray : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 then comes 2 for loops that check equality between first element in array and first element in newArray , how does that work ? because the comparation will always be between 1 and 0, 1 and 0, 2 and 0, the code works, but i simply dont get this line (array[i] == newArray[j])

Answer (score 1):

Change `j` loop to use `counter` as upper boundary, not `newArray.length`, so you only compare against values already copied into `newArray`. That way you never compare against an unassigned 0-valued slot.

For better performance, you should add a `break` statement after setting `isDuplicate = true`, since there is no need to keep scanning `newArray`.